# How can I fix typing a command name twice in zsh?

Tags: command-line, unix, zsh

So I have this (bad) habit of typing `git`, pausing for a sec to glance at the output of the `git status` command I just typed, then typing `git add ...` afterwards, resulting in the rather unsuccessful `git git add ...`.

Is there any functionality of zsh that would allow me to always replace `git git` with its singular equivalent?

Comment: haha I did that exact thing yesterday with another command.  wish i could help but i'm a bash user and don't understand that fancy z-shell.  :)

Comment: i do this all the time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't edit comments, so here is a working version for all bourne shells:

```
git(){ if [ "$1" = git ]; then shift; fi; command git "$@"; }
```

Comment: This seems to work brilliantly - many thanks. My shell-fu is quite weak, but I've slowly been strengthening and this shows more than a few things I think will come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be with a wrapper function:

```
function git { if [[ $1 == "git" ]]; then shift; fi; /path/to/git $@; }
```

This discards the second "git" if it's present and runs `git` with the parameters requested. This should work in zsh, Bash and ksh.